# making a pointer point to an array of characters in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char *arr;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int main()
{
    char *word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    strcpy(word, "jon jones");

    node *sentence;
    sentence->arr = word;         //Problem here
    printf("%s", sentence->arr);

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to dynamically allocate a character array. Put a string in there and then make the data element of the node point to the character array. When I run the program I get a segmentation fault. I suspect it is from the line that I labeled above. What I do not understand is, I made sentence->arr point to the first element of the word array. Why would it crash like that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note off topic:There is [no need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) to cast a result of `malloc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a pointer to node but this node has not been allocated.
Use :

    `node sentence;
    sentence.arr = word;
    printf("%s", sentence.arr);`

It should be better.
You can also use gdb for finding out which line causes the fault.

Comment: You should also free the dynamically allocated memory when it is no longer useful.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this and know how to do it. I was working on a much larger program but I couldnt get past this hump for awhile so I tried making a smaller program to understand the mechanics of why "this" or "that" wasnt working. Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

```
node *sentence;
sentence->arr = word;         //Problem here
```

Pointer `sentence` declared but it is not initialized and dereference so it causes undefined behavior.

Allocate memory before dereferencing it -

```
node *sentence;
sentence=malloc(sizeof(*sentence));
```

Also if you want to make nodes then use `strcpy`instead of this -

```
sentence->arr = word;       // but allocate memory to `arr` before copying
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your sentence variable.

Following works for me

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char *arr;
    struct node *next;
}node;

int main()
{
    char *word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    strcpy(word, "jon jones");

    node *sentence = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); // Initialize node area
    sentence->arr = word; 
    printf("%s", sentence->arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either alloc memory for `node` as you did for `word` or use a struct instead of struct pointer.

```
node *sentence;
sentence = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
sentence->arr = word;         
printf("%s", sentence->arr);
```

or

```
node sentence;
sentence.arr = word;         
printf("%s", sentence->arr);
```